# How to make async action method that call to external c# dll

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core-webapi

I have action method in my ASP.NET Core Web API project
that call to function in external C# dll.
These functions do calculations to the data that I pass to them and return an output to me.
How I do my action function asynchronous?
And is it even necessary to do so?

```
      [HttpPost]       
    public IActionResult SetClac([FromBody] CalcRequest calcRequest)
    {
        try
        {
            
            IClacSdk clacSdk = new CalcSdk();
            ClacResult clacResult = clacSdk.clac(calcRequest.id , calcRequest.username)
                                                                            
            CustomeResponse customeResponse = new CustomeResponse()
            {
                ErrorDescription = clacResult.ErrorDescription,
                ErrorNum = clacResult.ErrorNum,
                ClacResult = clacResult.Result
            };
            return Ok(customeResponse);
        }
         catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, (GetErrorFormat(exc)));
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How i do my action function asynchronous?

You can wrap them in `Task.Run` (though it will not make the operation "truly" async). I.e.:

```cs
ClacResult clacResult = await Task.Run(() => clacSdk.clac(calcRequest.id , calcRequest.username));
```

> And is it even necessary to do so?

No. Even more - in context of ASP.NET Core in general case it is recommended not to do so, because it can negatively affect server throughput (though if you have several calculation which you want to perform in parallel and individual response time is a priority you can leverage `Task.Run`).

If you want to dig deeper there are multiple resources to start:

1. [Asynchronous Programming in .NET - Introduction, Misconceptions, and Problems](https://wapplegate.com/asynchronous-programming/)
2. [Official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) (in this context [this one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) discussing I/O-bound and CPU-bound code can be useful)
3. Articles by Stephen Cleary (especially [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), which I find very interesting)